# dynamic design pattern

Tags: oop, design-patterns

I have a class named 'Employee'. Within the class is a method named getAgentsByHierarchy and it returns an array of all the agents with their corresponding ID and some other information.

```
Array{              
  [0] => Array{
     [0] => code
     [1] => id  
     [2] => name    
     [3] => role
  }
}
```

I am extending this to two classes named 'Production' and 'Payroll'. These two classes have fetchAll() methods that calls Employee.getAgentsByHierarchy() and fetches all the agents and *ONE* extra data/field.

So when I call Production.fetchAll(), this is what it should return:

```
Array{              
 [0] => Array{
    [0] => code
    [1] => id   
    [2] => name 
    [3] => role
    [4] => production_figures_in_digits
 }
}
```

And when I call Payroll.fetchAll(), this is what it should return:

```
Array{              
 [0] => Array{
    [0] => code
    [1] => id   
    [2] => name 
    [3] => role
    [4] => payroll_figures_in_digits
 }
}
```

How do I go about this kind of design ?

My solution would be to include a parameter in the getAgentsByHierarchy() method that checks if the callee is from Production class or from Payroll class so that it would know what data to return. But then I think this way is not OOP way of doing things because if there's a new class that extends Salesforce, i would have to hardcode getAgentsByHierarchy() again to meet the requirements of the new class.

PS. I am new to design pattern, please forgive me with the way i wrote the title.

Comment: Which class has the information of `production_figures_in_digits` and `payroll_figures_in_digits`, is `Class Employee` stores all the information?

Comment: @lostyzd, I would have a method inside Production class that returns the production figures of an employee. Same thing with payroll_figures, that is, a separate method inside Payroll class that returns the payroll_figures.

Comment: Production itself can get  figures of an employee without calling some method in Employee?

Comment: @lostyzd, but it has to know first which employee it is getting the figures from. That is what getAgentsByHierarchy() does. It reads through the db and retrieves all the agents in the agents table. But if I do something like Production.fetchAll(), it uses the same code with that of getAgentsByHierarchy(), but each time it retrieves an agent information, it calls another method that retrieves and calculates the production figures for that agent.

Comment: Inheritance should be used only if there is  <child> "is a" <parent> relationship. Otherwise Composition is the way to go

Answer (score 1):

In ideal object oriented written application the parent class should never be concerned about the behavior of it's Child classes. Its the child class which is inheriting has to abide by the contracts of parent class.

So the Employee class should not be concerned about the existence of Production, Payroll or any other class inheriting from Employee class.

Ideally getAgentsByHierarchy should be overridden in Production and Payroll (or any other future child class) to embed the information specific to them in the array.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking of just overriding getAgentsByHierarchy() in the Production and Payroll classes. But thing is, i will just be adding a line or two, not entirely changing the code. Should I still go for it ?

Comment: Yes you should do it, in fact its a good thing that you have to write a little code in the overridden function :)

Comment: after some more reading about oop and design patterns, i should not be using inheritance in the first place, because Productions and Payroll are not Salesforce. I'm thinking of Composition because Salesforce has-a Productions and Payroll... does this makes sense ?

Answer (score 0):

If `Production` has the information, to lower coupling, do it like this

```
Production.fetchAll() {
    Employee.getAgentsByHierarchy();
    Production.getFiguresInDigits();
    // some method to combine them then return
}
```

And the same with `Payroll`

Comment: Yes, I could do this. But doing so would require two iterations. First iteration, getting all the agents. Second iteration, loop through the array of agents and get their respective figures. I am finding a way to just make a single iteration for this problem.

Comment: @pneftali From what I know, you still need two or more iterations if you use `Production.fetchAll()`.

Comment: I guess you are right. But as much as possible, my design should avoid using two or more loops. The agents table currently has less than 1k rows. The productions table, however, will continue to expand overtime. Currently, it has 12k rows. I am still figuring out a better design for this.

Comment: @pneftali You mean there is a table store everything like `agent id`, `production_figures_in_digits` and `payroll_figures_in_digits`?

Comment: There are basically three tables. Employee, Production, and Payroll. Employee contains all the basic information of an employee. Production contains all the timestamped records with regards to every employee's output. The same with Payroll table.

Comment: @pneftali Well, one way is to implement `Production.getAllFiguresInDigits()`, then combine them by your self, but this is not a good design, because it may be achieved on your database(such as sql).